# Remove case sensitive duplicate elements from list in java

Tags: java, string

So I have let's say a list of Strings like {"a","A","b","B","C","D","d","E"}

My requirement is that I want to remove duplicate elements from this string. I will specify in beginning whether elements to be considered for removing will be in lowercase or uppercase.

I know traditional approaches like using a for loop and then processing each element based on requirement. But I want to know much better approach to achieve this using java.

This is my approach :

String[] str = { "a", "A", "b", "B", "C", "D", "d", "E" };
        HashSet s = new HashSet();

```
    for (String alphabet : str) {

        if (alphabet.equals(alphabet.toUpperCase())) {

            s.add(alphabet);
        }
    }       

    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: What does better means? Performance wise?

Comment: Yeah , not only performance but something like a one-liner , example by using streams in java 8 or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = { "a", "A", "b", "B", "C", "D", "d", "E" };
        int option = 1;// `0` for lowercase and `1` for UPPERCASE
        Set<String> set;
        if (option == 0) {
            set = Arrays.stream(str).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        } else {
            set = Arrays.stream(str).map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }

        // Display
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

Comment: The title says *Remove case sensitive duplicate items from the list*.  Since `C` and `E` have no duplicates should they be removed? Shouldn't one of the modes print `[a, b, C, d, E]`?  Or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, please include any code you've already tried. Because you haven't, I will *explain* some of the ways it is possible.

A `for` loop is definitely the easiest (and, correct me if I'm wrong, fastest) way to do this. You could use a foreach loop (`for(thingContained name : groupOfContainedThings)`) and check if there is a difference between the original character and one that has had the `.toLowerCase()` method called on it. if they're different, then it was an uppercase letter.

You could also instead use `.compareTo(String str)` with the above `for` loop, and check if the value is 0 (no difference). You can read more about it [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/). This is more versatile, and I recommend it because it will work with longer `String`s too!

Comment: Sorry for not including my code , I have added it in my original post. I am looking for using any utility methods in collection API or streams to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).  Sets don't allow you to add duplicate items, and they are case sensitive.  An example is below:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("A");
set.add("a");
set.add("b");
set.add("B");
set.add("C");
set.add("D");
set.add("d");
set.add("E");

set.add("E"); //duplicate element
set.add("e"); //not a duplicate element

System.out.println(set.toString());
```

Output:

```
[A, a, b, B, C, D, d, E, e]
```

Comment: But it's only limited to upper case , my requirement is that it can be an upper case or lower case string.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood what you wanted to do.  I would follow Arvind's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code below.

The idea is to create a count map of string. If an element has occurred once, add it directly to the de-duplicated list. If it has occurred more than once, you need to check which version of the element you want to keep(either lowercase or uppercase).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemoveDuplicateCaseInsensitive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList("a", "A", "b", "B", "C", "D", "d", "E");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String caseToRemove = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("caseToRemove is = " + caseToRemove); // to be inputted by user
        Map<String, Long> countMapOfString =
                inputList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println("countMapOfString is = " + countMapOfString);

        List<String> deDuplicatedStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        inputList.stream().forEach(element -> {
            // element which have occurred only once should be added straight away
            if (countMapOfString.get(element.toLowerCase()) == 1) {
                deDuplicatedStringList.add(element);
            } else {
                if (caseToRemove.equalsIgnoreCase("UpperCase")) { // want to remove uppercase
                    if (!deDuplicatedStringList.contains(element.toLowerCase())) {
                        deDuplicatedStringList.add(element.toLowerCase());
                    }
                } else if (caseToRemove.equalsIgnoreCase("LowerCase")) { // want to remove lowercase
                    if (!deDuplicatedStringList.contains(element.toUpperCase())) {
                        deDuplicatedStringList.add(element.toUpperCase());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("deDuplicatedStringList is = " + deDuplicatedStringList);
    }
}
```

When you run with `LowerCase` as input the output of the program is

```
caseToRemove is = LowerCase
countMapOfString is = {a=2, b=2, c=1, d=2, e=1}
deDuplicatedStringList is = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

When you run with `UpperCase` as input the output of the program is

```
caseToRemove is = UpperCase
countMapOfString is = {a=2, b=2, c=1, d=2, e=1}
deDuplicatedStringList is = [a, b, C, d, E]
```

Hope this helps.